# Issue sizing image inside UIView | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I have an image inside of a UI View that seems to look good on an iPhone X and Above but is very squished when displayed on an iPhone 8 Plus and Below.

The following is how I am sizing and maintaining the image:

```
let LogoView: UIImageView = {
   let theImageView = UIImageView()
   theImageView.image = UIImage(named: ".png")
   theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   return theImageView
}()

    // MARK: Layout
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        //Logo
        self.LogoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        self.LogoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 62),
        self.LogoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.AlertView.trailingAnchor,constant: -110),
        self.LogoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.AlertView.leadingAnchor,constant: 110),
        self.LogoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.buttonDismiss.bottomAnchor,constant: -60),
        
        //Dismiss Button
        self.buttonDismiss.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        self.buttonDismiss.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.AlertView.trailingAnchor,constant: -15),
        self.buttonDismiss.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.AlertView.leadingAnchor,constant: 15),
        self.buttonDismiss.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.AlertView.bottomAnchor,constant: -25),
    ])
```

How can this be improved?

Comment: Please see my updated post

Comment: there is conflict in width and (leading ,trailing )

Comment: You can set width or leading, trailing not both

Comment: @KishanBhatiya how can this be corrected?

Comment: do you want to center ImageView ? or align with leading or trailing ?

Comment: I would like to center the image and keep the correct aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

You can either have width or (leading , trailing) both ...

```
self.LogoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
self.LogoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 62),
self.LogoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.AlertView.centerXAnchor,constant: 0),
self.LogoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.buttonDismiss.bottomAnchor,constant: -60),
```